# Python save function with argumnets to variable without to call a function

Tags: python

It is easy to save function into a variable like

```
pr = print
pr(5)  # 5
```

But if this possible to save function with arguments without a call, like

```
some_var = defer print(5)  # No call! 
some_var()  # 5
```

I tried to use lambda, but it's lead to syntaxys error `l = lambda 5:

Why I need it? For example to no repeat multiple "if" branches:

example:

```
def foo()
l1 = lambda: 1
l2 = lambda: 2
if 1:
    func = l1
elif 2:
    func = l2
else:
   func = some_outer_func, some_inner_func  
return func  # To use "func" need additional "if" branches for type and length of a returned value
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#functools.partial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#functools.partial) takes a function of many arguments and returns a function with fewer arguments with some of the arguments "saved"

```
from functools import partial

print_five = partial(print, 5)
print_five()  # 5
```

It also works with keyword arguments

```
def foo(a, b=False):
    print(a, b)

bar = partial(foo, b=True)
foo(1)  # 1 False
bar(1)  # 1 True
```

Comment: Very unfortunately that python does not have special key word for this. Anyway I can't use it with chunks of functions like `outer(inner(defered_func))  # need partial for every func`

Comment: Are you looking to chain function calls?

Answer (score 1):

The way with lambda:

```
pr = lambda: print(5)
pr()
```